# VSTS Configuring Agent pools and queues

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm new to VSTS - using it to manage test case and associated regression automation tests. Just wanted to check if I'm on the rights track.

Thanks for your help ...

Question about Agent pools and queues. We would like to define a number of agents (in a pool) and and agent queue to support the agent pool.

I'm reading the article below:

Agent pools and queues
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=vsts

Using this configuration described above - I could have a number of builds/release in the queue and they would be distributed to agents in the pool as they become free. This is how it will work.

Out current configuration:

We have one Build Pipeline and one Release Pipeline  as described below.

Then we will execute a number of builds (in the Build Pipeline) and assocated releases (in the Release pipeline).

Currently we are using the configuration below - no pools.

Release and Build

Build Pipeline
- TestBuild 
- Will build the software (tests)

Release Pipeline 
- ReleaseTest 
- Will run the software (tests)

Comment: Your question is not clear and possibly not a question. Please can you re-phrase this into a question so it's intent is clear

Comment: Sorry - We want to execute multiple releases across multiple agents. Reading the microsoft documentation - seems this can be done using Agent pools. I suppose the question is ... Can we use VSTS Agent pool(s) to execute multiple releases concurrently on multiple agents? Thanks :-)

Comment: @macgowan, Did you resolve this issue in your side? Could you get useful information from Phil's suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Private Agent, which are managed in VSTS in agent pools, to run build concurrently however it’s worth noting you pay for [concurrent builds on agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs-vsts?view=vsts) nowadays so you can have 15 agents but if you only have 10 concurrency licenses only 10 builds or release will run. You can achieve concurrency on hosted agents by [buying more Microsoft Hosted Agent Concurrency licenses](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.build-release-hosted-pipelines).